# Inconsistently getting error (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber

I am new to cucumber,while running script at times I am getting error

`(Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)`

I am not finding any particular pattern to it.
Any help will be dearly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Apparently you are waiting for something that sometimes happens before Watir's default timeout and sometimes it exceeds that, causing the error you described. Have a look at http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401885/timeouterror-in-rails-application-using-watir

Comment: Thanks, @rkon but little more doubt.e.g
'@browser.text_field(:id, "unified-itin-emailId").when_present().set(email)'
in this code in when_present(120) whatever time I give it does not reflect and the error continues.saying after this seconds timeout.
Is there difference between this timeout and browser timeout e.g @browser.wait_until(120)

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure you're requiring the proper library for watir-webdriver/wait.

```
require "watir-webdriver/wait"
```

Watir has a few methods of declaring wait times on objects, for example (via [Watir Webdriver/Waiting](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/)):

**Explicit waits**

There are four built in methods that you can use to make your waiting experience more pleasant (and remove those evil sleep statements from your code)

```
Watir::Wait.until { ... }   #=> you can wait for a block to be true
object.when_present.set     #=> you can do something when it’s present
object.wait_until_present   #=> you just wait until something is present & visible
object.wait_while_present   #=> you just wait until something disappears
```

Watir also has a way to set the implicit wait time between execution on the driver occurs.

**Implicit waits**

As an alternative, you can use the WebDriver’s implicit waits to specify a maximum time (in seconds) the script will try to find an element before timing out. This is done by setting the property of the underlying driver:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3 #=> always wait 3 seconds
```