# wait_until block is giving time out error

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

This is the code which is failing for me.

```
link(:continue, :text => 'Continue Shopping')

def verify_cart
    wait_until(60) do
      continue_element.visible?
    end
  end
```

To make it work I have tried solutions here:
[Inconsistently getting error (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340134/inconsistently-getting-error-watirwaittimeouterror)
and [Timeout::Error in Rails application using Watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401885/timeouterror-in-rails-application-using-watir) but none worked for me.

I have also tried by increasing the time.

Then I tried by increasing the at `implicit wait` from 3 seconds to 20 seconds and instead of using `wait_until` block I simply used `.visible?` and it worked.

```
link(:continue, :text => 'Continue Shopping')

continue_element.visible?

 #def verify_cart
 #   wait_until(60) do
 #     continue_element.visible?
 #   end
 # end
```

**Now question is when element was there why `wait_until` kept on failing?**

Comment: @JustinKo could you put your thoughts on this.

Comment: What do you mean that by using `continue_element.visible?` instead of `wait_until(60){ continue_element.visible? }` works? Do mean that the exception goes away and that the later steps of your script work as expected? `continue_element.visible?` just returns whether the element is present. If you have simply removed the `wait_until` part of the `verify_cart` method, then depending on how your script is written, it is possible that `verify_cart` passes even though the link is not present.

Comment: @JustinKo element is always there, it is visible(I have tested it). Now problem is when I put this statement `continue_element.visible?` out of `wait_until` block it passes but when I put it inside it, it is giving time out error.

Comment: I think you need to provide more context of your problem. We need to see (1) the HTML and related Javascript and CSS that reproduce the problem and (2) the test that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

```
continue_element.visible?
```

is not going to raise an error, it is just going to return a boolean. It sounds like this element doesn't actually end up visible, and this would still raise the error regardless of the implicit wait:

```
raise unless continue_element.visible?
```

Also, a better pattern for this is:

```
continue.wait_until_present
```

or

```
continue.when_present.click
```

`.present?` just means `.exists?` && `.visible?` which is actually what you want, and this pattern will give you a better error message.

Comment: I already know difference between `.present?`, `.visible?` and `.exists?`. And you are wrong `.visible?`. gives error `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element` on failure, I tested it. Last, question still stands **why wait_until()** not working.

Comment: #visible? gives an error if it doesn't exist and returns false if it exists and isn't displayed.
#present? rescues the error for it not existing and returns false if it either doesn't exist or exists and isn't visible.
It sounds like your element isn't actually visible. Can you do a sleep 60 and raise unless element.present?

Comment: @paul, I think your comment regarding the `visible?` is confusing the Watir vs Page-Object API. You are right that Watir's `visible?` will throw an exception if the element does not exist. However, Titus is right that `continue_element.visible?`, which is Page-Object code, will return false if the element does not exist. Despite the name, Page-Object's `visible?` method actually calls Watir's `present?` method.

Comment: I don't know anything about Page-Object code, and @paul doesn't mention using that gem. in Watir, Element#visible? will only throw an error if the element doesn't exist, not if it exists, but is not displayed. Both examples above are consistent with the continue element existing in the DOM, but not being displayed. The wait block would return false for the visible call until it timed out and raised a timeout error. The implicit wait with the visible call would return false and not raise any error.