# .visible? doesn't give false when element not visible

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

There are test cases where I want to check:

1. Load more button visible
2. Load more not visible

I wrote this method:

```
 def loadmore_button_visible?
    wait_until(20) do
      @browser.refresh
      link_element(:title => 'load_more').visible?
    end
  end
```

and used it as

`expect(on(ProductViewPage).loadmore_button_visible?).to be_true` for "test1" 
and `expect(on(ProductViewPage).loadmore_button_visible?).to be_false` for "test2"

It works test1 but for test2 it gives Time Out Error. I think I have asked similar question here [wait_until block is giving time out error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450250/wait-until-block-is-giving-time-out-error)
but this time I think its not about `wait_until` block as `wait_until` works for "test1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `wait_until` block is expecting to resolve to true. If it does not, it will raise a TimeoutError. The first test passes because `link_element(:title => 'load_more').visible?` is true and that satisfies the `wait_until` method. If you want the method to return true and false, you need to catch the error and explicitly return false. Something like:

```
def loadmore_button_visible?
  begin
    wait_until(20) do
      @browser.refresh
      link_element(:title => 'load_more').visible?
    end
  rescue TimeoutError 
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: you are right, but question is why it is giving `timeout` it supposed to give `false`, because anything can cause `timeout`. Slow internet speed also can cause `timeout` in that case falsely give `false`.

Comment: The method you're using calls `Wait.until`, which is supposed to return true or raise an error. The docs are clear on that. http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Wait#until-class_method